# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'tablename'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

```
cis.statbib.org: script/console 
Loading development environment (Rails 2.2.2)
Article.founc>> Article.count()
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'article'
    from /home/hadley/web/cis.statbib.org/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:29:in `table_structure'
    from /home/hadley/web/cis.statbib.org/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/misc.rb:39:in `returning'
...
```

But it certainly seems like it's there in the database:

```
db: sqlite3 development.sqlite3 
SQLite version 3.2.8
sqlite> select count(*) from author;
168600
```

I've just updated all my gems, etc. What's going wrong?

Comment: It's looking for article, but you're checking for author.

Comment: For an `Article` model, it should look for an 'articles' table. Have you called `set_table_name` anywhere? And your console example looks in the 'author' table (which should probably be 'articles' anyways).

Comment: Ooops, that was just a silly typo.  I have a positive count in sql for article, and the same error in the console with Author.count().

Comment: So what about the table name? It normally looks for "articles" when you do things with `Article`. Are you using `set_table_name`?

Comment: I'm using ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names = false - but that shouldn't be a problem, should it?  My table names are singular.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem indeed. How are your migrations? Are they singular as well?

Comment: I don't have any migrations - it's a legacy database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be caused by a bug in ActiveRecord, http://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/99-sqlite-connection-failing.  Monkey-patching the file as described in that link fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Sarah Mei already pointed out in the comments, you are manually checking for "author" not "article."

However, something else might be off here as well.  Did you intentionally set the table name to "article" in your model?  By default, that should be looking for the "articles" (plural) table, so I suspect that there's more code that we're not seeing which could be causing trouble.

Comment: Yes, the table name is article, I have ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names = false in environment.rb (all my table names are singular)